# css issue when resizing windows

Tags: html, css

hi i am having issue with css as when i resize the windows the div is not placed properly as below

[image]

this is css involving the div

```
.similar_story_block_form {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size: 13px;
    left: 337px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    width: 337px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Html code

```
<div id="search-box-form">
  <div style="display:block;" class="similar_story_block_form">
     <div class="head">
        <p>What interest you?</p>
        <a onclick="javascript:closeSearchBox(event);" id="close-element-form" href="#"></a></div>
<ul>
 <li>
   <a no-confirm="" class="pushstate">
    <div col-400="" class="fleft"><p>No such business</p></div></a></li>
    <div class="head"><p>Nothing is found from <span style="color:red;font-weight:italic;">"s"</span></p>
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

currently i use chrome which give me the same issue. What am i missing here? Thank for your help

Comment: Positioned it absolute so it will stay in the same position regardless of what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put "position: relative;" or "position: absolute" on the "#search-box-form" element. That way the ".similar_story_block_form" position will be relative/absolute to the parent position. Instead of the global/body position.

Answer (score 1):

The parent of div with class `similar_story_block`_form which is `search-box-form` should have position relative, while as div with class `search-box-form` should have absolute position, you need to change the top and left values of `search-box-form` div. Make sure you also add `left:0;top:0;` to parent div which is `search-box-form`

Answer (score 0):

you have to give your style values of **left,top,width** in % rather than in pixels.

when you give it in pixels,the size and position becomes fix for standard browser size and not for re-sized ones.

if you give it in %,then it will automatically change it's width and position according to it's parent element.

For example,

```
 .similar_story_block_form{ width:80%; }
```

will make the "similar_story_block_form" be 80% in width of it's parent element. And if the parent element is body, it will automaticly change it's width together with the browser window width.